# What redirect to use with MSAL for a Chrome extension?

Tags: azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I'm writing a Chrome extension that needs to access an ASP.NET Core web API that demands an AAD access token. I'm trying to use the [msal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/msal) NPM package to offer an auth flow so the user can sign in to my extension with their existing AAD account, thereby giving my extension the access token it needs.

I got so far as a popup window that signs the user in, but before my extension gets the token, the popup window displays this error:

> ERR_UNSAFE_REDIRECT

I'm guessing this is because an https page is trying to redirect back to a URL with a `chrome-extension://` scheme. But how should I do it? This is the code I have now:

```
    var userAgentApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(applicationConfig.clientId, applicationConfig.authority, authCallback, {
        redirectUri: chrome.extension.getURL('popup.html'),
        cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
    });
    const idToken = await userAgentApplication.loginPopup(applicationConfig.scopes);
```

Answer (score 5):

I found out that I need to add the html page used in `redirectUri` to the `web_accessible_resources` array in my `manifest.json` file, as [documented here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources).

Comment: Ok. But how do you add the same uri to Azure AD App registgration?
It allows only https://... and http://localhost uri!

Comment: @hypers, add the redirect URI to the 'Mobile and desktop applications' section.

Comment: @MrRogers What about if we have injected some html code on page(at content_script) and place signin button there and not serving the content on web_accessible_resources