# Using Microsoft Graph API (msal library) from chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I'm working on chrome extension where i need to authenticate user against Microsoft account to use MSAL library (Graph API) from background scripts. But currently I'm getting error **AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application**

Unfortunately I cannot enter redirect uri starting with **chrome-extension://** in Microsoft portal.

Is there a way how to achieve this or is it a no go?

Edit:

OK it seems I can use **chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow** for this. But when requesting a token, the **client_secret** is required (wihtout this I get the 401 response code). Is it safe to include this **client_secret** in the background scripts of the extension?

If I see it correctly, the msal library does not require client_secret

Comment: Sounds like the perfect job for chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow, look for examples if needed.

Comment: @wOxxOm Yes this could be used for the authorization, but what about token acquiring? That has to be POST request that returns the token data in the response payload. And if I get it right, chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow only supports GET requests and returns URL in the callback.

Comment: Maybe this post can help you out, in case you have not already gone through it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52415398/what-redirect-to-use-with-msal-for-a-chrome-extension

Comment: @mikeek were you able to make this work? If yes can you answer your question would be a ton of help !

Answer (score 3):

MSAL.js supports different flows for authentication.

The one called ***implicit*** requires a login page (popup or redirected) to be displayed for the user to enter credentials. This flow does NOT require client_secret to be provided from your app.

To fight **AADSTS50011** error for this flow you need to make sure that redirect uri is registered with Azure AD. It's true that **chrome-extension://** urls don't comply with Azure requirements.

There is a solution exactly for the case - **chrome.identity.getRedirectURL()**. This function generates a redirect url of this kind:

```
https://<app-id>.chromiumapp.org/*
```

**app-id** is id of your extension and will change in development environment every time you change extension unpacked path. So make sure you update redirect uri with Azure timely. Other workaround for this is generating a key and including it into extension manifest. This way you can bake your app-id and redirect uri.

Please note that generated uri is fake and if you need to process response from authentication server then you should do so in the callback function:

```
chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(
  {
    url: authUrl,
    interactive: true
  },
  function (response) {
    // do stuff with code/token, etc.
  }
);
```

The ***client credentials grant*** flow works without user authorizing every time your app requests authentication. But it is not safe at all to store credentials inside browser extension.

There're more flows but I don't see them relevant for the original question case.